# awk judges and outputs all clumns that meet the conditions according to the specific column

Tags: awk

Here is my file which contains three cloumns and were separated by "\t", and the second cloumn was sparated by blank.

```
            1    a b c d e    Tom
            2    a b          Jason 
            3    c            Lisa
            4    e            Kim
```

I want to get the file which second column contains more than two elements，“NF>2”

```
            1    a b c d e    Tom
            2    a b          Jason
```

Benefiting from Ed Morton tip. I have tried  `less -S test.txt | awk -F "\t" '{print $2}' | awk 'NF>2'` but i can't get the whole line.  actually, i always confused how to output the entire row that satisfies the condition based on a certain condition in a column. I only konw the some simple situation like `cat test.txt | awk '{if( )print$0}'`. Can you give me some advice? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think you mean "**at least** two elements" rather than "**more than** two elements".  The "Jason" line wouldn't print otherwise, it has exactly two elements, not "more than two".  There's a difference between `>` and `>=` and it is essential to be **precise** in your thinking, speech, and code when programming..

Comment: The script [I provided yesterday](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/711002/133219), `awk 'NF>3' file`, does exactly what you're asking for again here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```bash
$ awk -F'\t' 'split($2,a," ") >= 2' input.txt 
1       a b c d e       Tom
2       a b     Jason
```

Using TAB as the field separator, this prints each line where `$2` contains at least two strings separated by a space.

`split()` splits a string (`$2`) into an array (`a`) using a regular expression as the separator (in this case, a single space).  See `man awk` for details on the `split` function.

This awk one-liner doesn't use or care about the contents of array `a`, it just checks the return value of the split function - which is the number of number of elements the string was split into.  If that's greater than or equal to 2, the condition evaluates as true and the whole line is printed.

---

BTW, if you want to better understand how this works, seeing the number of elements in each $2 would help.  e.g. with something like this, which assigns the return value of `split` to variable `n` and then prints it along with the input line:

```
$ awk -F'\t' '{n=split($2,a," ");printf "(n=%i)\t%s\n",n,$0}' input.txt 
(n=5)   1       a b c d e       Tom
(n=2)   2       a b     Jason
(n=1)   3       c       Lisa
(n=1)   4       e       Kim
```

So the first line has 5 elements, the second has 2, and the last two lines have only one each.